# How to inject a Type instead of an instance into a constructor using Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is it possible to inject a type into a constructor instead of an instance?
If so how is this achieved? I want to avoid explicitly registering a factory method or resolving an instance in situ if possible.

```
public interface IJob { }
public class TheJob : IJob { }

public interface IService
{
    string GetTypeDesc();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private Type _jobType;

    public Service(Type jobType)
    {
        _jobType = jobType;
    }

    public string GetTypeDesc()
    {
        return _jobType.ToString();
    }
}
```

It seems even when registering the type with explicit constructor definition, Unity wants to inject an instance into the type place holder.

```
Type jobType = typeof(TheJob);    
(new UnityContainer()).RegisterType<IService, Service>(new InjectionConstructor(jobType));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `InjectionConstructor` takes an array of objects. If the type of an object passed to the constructor of `InjectionConstructor` (in the array) is of type `Type`, unity will try to resolve that type and then pass the result into the constructor (of 'Service` for example).

For example, if you use `new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMyOtherService))`, then unity will expect that the constructor of `Service` takes an instance of type `IMyOtherService` and will use the container to resolve such type. In other words `Type` is a special case that you need to handle in a specific way.

To solve your issue, you should tell Unity that the `Type` you are passing is actually a constructor parameter. You can do this like this:

```
new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter(jobType))
```

This forces unity to treat `jobType` as a constructor parameter.

For more details see the `InjectionParameterValue.ToParameter` method here: https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/master/source/Src/Unity-CoreClr/Injection/InjectionParameterValue.cs

Comment: If I do this with RegisterType<,> I get an error: The type UnitySample.Service does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (RuntimeType).  I'm starting to think this is not possible without some wrapper or intermediate factory which is a shame.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I had a problem in my original code. Please ignore. Is there any way to make the job registration simpler? I used to register like this in main()  container.RegisterType<IJob, TheSpecificJob>().  So keep the InjectionConstructor common, but hookup different IJob implementations?

Comment: @user183872, can you provide a complete (minimal) example? If it is different from the current question, I suggest you create another one.

Comment: you're right. I have several windows services which use common scheduling code which doesn't reference the underlying service. I kind of like just wiring a job instance to a type in the main() rather than specifying the more complex InjectionConstruction each time.  Probably splitting hairs;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to inject a type into a constructor instead of an instance?

A `System.Type` is an ambiguous type, just like primitive types such as `System.String` and `System.Int32`. They are considered ambiguous, because at runtime there are multiple (or many) possible values of the type. This prevents a DI Container from automatically resolving and injecting an instance of such value for you.

This means that you should manually supply the value to Unity. This can be done using the `InjectionConstructor` (as you are already doing):

```
.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new InjectionConstructor(jobType))
```

Or using a `InjectionFactory`:

```
.Register<IService>(new InjectionFactory(c => new Service(jobType)))
```

Comment: The above causes a Unity exception though (The type UnitySample.Service does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (TheJob).)

Comment: @user183872: should work. [Read this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507497(v=pandp.30).aspx) for information about it.